# Inno Setup Setting named pipe on Windows x64

Tags: installation, registry, inno-setup, setup-project

I have a problem with my installation using Inno Setup. I need to install SQL 2012 Express x64 version, but when it finishes installing, the idea is already let 100% configured environment, or in my case with Named Pipes.

Must enter the named pipe via record, until then use the following two lines:

**[Registry]**
***x64*** - 
`Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo; ValueType: string; ValueName: DevServer; ValueData: DBNMPNTW,\\.\PIPE\MSSQL$SQL2012EXPRESS\sql\query`

***x86 (works)*** - `Root: HKLM; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo; ValueType: string; ValueName: DevServer; ValueData: DBNMPNTW,\\.\PIPE\MSSQL$SQL2012EXPRESS\sql\query`

For the x86 version it works 100% correctly. As for the x64 version does not work, I notice that the path that should be created in "regedit" does not exist, but if create manually by Configuration Manager everything works properly.

I tested also creating a batch to run a .reg file during installation and not getting hit as well.

Remembering my problem is only for the x64 version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Inno Setup installer is 32-bit application, so `SOFTWARE` gets redirected to `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node` by default.

You have to use `Root: HKLM64` to explicitly avoid the redirection.

You will probably also want to add `Check: IsWin64` to make sure the entry is not processed on 32-bit installations, as it would cause an error.

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM64; Subkey: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Client\ConnectTo; ValueType: string; \
    ValueName: DevServer; ValueData: DBNMPNTW,\\.\PIPE\MSSQL$SQL2012EXPRESS\sql\query; \
    Check: IsWin64
```

See [`[Registry]` section documentation](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection).

---

Or [use 64-bit install mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls).